# Is there a way to generate an Array or Hash of Siteprism objects currently on a page

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, site-prism

I'm still new(ish), to POM, but I've found the syntax and general structure quite strong, so now I'm looking to advanced techniques.

I have a dynamic page, and for each of the sections I am running the following code/psuedo code

```
if has_SECTVAR1?
   $LOG.info("Stuff")
end

if has_SECTVAR2?
   $LOG.info("Stuff")
end
```

What I want to do is something like this.

```
ALLSECTIONARRAYS.each do |var|
  if has_var?
    $LOG.info("Stuff")
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an array of element names using `#mapped_items`. The more interesting part is checking if those exist on the page by calling `#has_element?`.

The abstract version of what you want to do is call a method on an object given its name as a string. To do this, use `#send`:

```
MyObject.send("method_name", *args)
```

Or in your case:

```
MyPage.send("has_element?")
```

Finally, to iterate over all elements:

```
MyPage.mapped_items.each do |item|
  if MyPage.send("has_#{item}?")
    $LOG.info("Stuff")
  end
end
```

Comment: Haha, as you messaged this I already got the send portion. Will update my code that I have now.

Will try the mapped_items function today, if that works then I'm all done!